# Send an ad-hoc WOL packet without depending on binaries

Tags: networking, wake-on-lan

Under a `VPN` exist a variety of machines that have their mobo's `WOL` protocol enabled. With that said, I wish to create a script that creates a `WOL` packet that can be sent to a specific machine of the network without depending on any binaries (e.g., `etherwake` or `wakeonlan`).

One can easily implement the code required to generate the byte-stream of the magic packet after reading the respective paper [[1](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/20213.pdf)] but I do not have the knowledge on how to transmit/send the packet from inside the `VPN` network.

So in the following scenario:

```
+---+  +---+  +---+  +---+
| A |  | B |  | C |  | D |
+---+  +---+  +---+  +---+      __   _
   \______\_____\__VPN__\______(  )_( )_
                              ( internet)_________ +---+
                              _(__)_(_)_           | W |
                                                   +---+
```

With me having remote access (e.g., via `ssh`) to either of the machines of the `VPN` and saying e.g., that I am in the machine `D` which can see the rest in the local network, how can I send a packet to wake machine `B` for instance (once again, without relying on any kind of software/library) ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems tricky without any software/library.  Basic python can achieve this, with just the regular default libs, see example at https://github.com/multipetros/wol.py/blob/master/wol.py

Comment: You cannot do that without using *any* kind of software. You have the option of using software that is already installed (and for that, we need to know which software is installed; there are quite a few tools which might be already there, like [netcat](https://gist.github.com/SteveMarshall/c3d38b220e2a621d68c9b7d4e376a82f), or programming languages like Python), or you can copy software to the target machine via your ssh connection to do it. There is no in-built shell command for wake-on-lan packets, sorry.

Comment: Typicallly WoL packets can't cross VPNs; it works by sending a packet to a specific MAC address, and MACs are layer-2.  VPNs normally work at layer 3 or higher.   In an enterprise environment you may have "relays" (potentially built into switches or routers) on each subnet that can send the packet locally.  So in your environment I would put something small (maybe an rPi) that's always on that can send the WoL packet.  From W login to the rPi and then use etherwake.

Comment: @StephenHarris That is correct, I do not wish to send a `WOL` packet throught the internet to the VPN and then to the machinery. I assume that I have already access to either of the machines (A,B,C,D) hidden under the VPN and I wish to wake a "neighbouring" one. My formulation of the question was not correct. Excuse me.

Comment: @steve No no, well by dependencies I am only referring to complete binaries like the ones mentioned above in the post and not i.e., the standard libraries of `python`. The example that you have provided seems promising. I will investigate.